# Missing drush in OpenShift Drupal module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, openshift, drush

i have sshd into my OpenShift Drupal install with the intent of changing my Drupal admin password ..however the drush tool does not seem to be installed

[drupal-.rhcloud.com 56f94fb97628e12ab700005f]> drush --help
bash: drush: command not found
[drupal-.rhcloud.com 56f94fb97628e12ab700005f]>

i am using :

Drupal 7

is there something that needs doing to get that drush addition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seams openshift drush is not working for every bodies.its happened because of using old PHP version, which is not working by new composer, SO you need to make one DIY app in openshift and install manually drush and new version of php (php >=5.5.0 ).

[Drush installing in Openshift RHC](https://github.com/elasa-Sites/openshift-drush-installing)

So you could install drush manually by this codes:

```
 mkdir ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/composer
curl -ss https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/composer
cd /tmp
rm -rf tt
mkdir tt
cd tt
#wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drush-7.x-5.9.tar.gz
wget https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/archive/master.zip && unzip master.zip
rm master.zip
mv * drush
chmod u+x drush/drush

#tar xzf drush-7.x-5.9.tar.gz && rm drush-7.x-5.9.tar.gz && cd drush && mv drush drush_my
mkdir ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/
mkdir ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/drush
mv  /tmp/tt/drush/* ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/drush && cd ../..
rm -rf tt
export PATH=${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/drush:$PATH
cd ~/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/action_hooks
echo "export PATH=${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/drush:$PATH
#export PATH=${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/composer:$PATH" >> ~/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/action_hooks/start
chmod 755 start

echo "export PATH=${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/drush:$PATH
export PATH=${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/composer:$PATH
alias drush='${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/drush/drush'
alias drush='/opt/rh/php54/root/usr/bin/php ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/drush/drush.php'" >> ~/app-root/data/.bash_profile

cd ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/drush
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
mv composer.phar composer.phar0
php composer.phar0 install 
php composer.phar0 update
#composer config --global bin-dir /usr/local/bin
#composer config --global bin-dir /opt/rh/php54/root/usr/bin
composer config --global vendor-dir ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/composer
php composer install
php ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/composer/composer.phar --no-interaction --no-ansi --no-scripts  --optimize-autoloader --working-dir=${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/drush install
cd ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/drush
# Drush settings

cp drush.php drush.php0
echo "\$options['uri'] = \$_ENV['OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS'];
  \$options['root'] = \$_ENV['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'].'php';" >> drush.php 
if [[ -f ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/drush/drush.php ]]; then 
    echo "$repo_top = getcwd().'/..';
  $options['config'] = $repo_top . '/drush/drushrc.php'; "
  else
    echo "<?php 
      $repo_top = getcwd().'/..';
  $options['config'] = $repo_top . '/drush/drushrc.php'; " >> drush.php 
fi

cat << EOF >>drushrc.php
<?php 
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
if (array_key_exists('OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME', \$_SERVER)) {
  \$src = \$_SERVER;
} else {
  \$src = \$_ENV;
}
\$options['uri'] =\$src['OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS']; 
       \$options['root'] =\$src['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'].'php'; 
       \$options['db-url']=\$src['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL'].\$src['OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS'];
        \$options['backup-dir'] = '/tmp';
       ?>
EOF
echo " \$options['backup-dir'] = '/tmp';">> drushrc.php
#nano drush.php 
drush status
#install mysql
: <<'end_long_comment' 
#
cd /tmp
wget http://wiki.diahosting.com/down/lnmp/mysql-5.1.46.tar.gz
nohup sh -c "./configure --prefix=${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/mysql --enable-assembler --with-charset=utf8 --enable-thread-safe-client --with-extra-charsets=all --with-big-tables &&
make && make install"> $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/mysql_install.log /dev/null 2>&1 & tail -f  $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/mysql_install.log

chown -R mysql:mysql ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/mysql

cp support-files/my-medium.cnf /etc/my.cnf

sed -i 's#\[mysqld\]#\[mysqld\]\nbasedir=/usr/local/mysql\ndatadir=/var/lib/mysql\n#' /etc/my.cnf
sed -i 's#log-bin=mysql-bin#\#log-bin=mysql-bin#' /etc/my.cnf
sed -i 's#binlog_format=mixed#\#binlog_format=mixed#' /etc/my.cnf

${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/mysql/bin/mysql_install_db --basedir=${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/mysql  --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql

cp ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/mysql/share/mysql/mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysqld
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/mysqld

/etc/init.d/mysqld start

${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password $myrootpwd

chkconfig mysqld on

#ln -s ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/mysql/bin/myisamchk /usr/bin/
#ln -s ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/mysql/bin/mysql /usr/bin/
#ln -s ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/mysql/bin/mysqldump /usr/bin/


end_long_comment
cd
export pass=$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD
export user=$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME
mysql -u $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME 
DROP DATABASE drupal2;
CREATE DATABASE drupal2;
#CREATE USER druser@localhost;
#CREATE USER druser2@$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST;
CREATE USER 'druser'@'$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST' IDENTIFIED BY 'druser';
#CREATE USER 'juddi'@'$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST' IDENTIFIED BY 'juddi';
#SET PASSWORD FOR druser@localhost= PASSWORD("password");
SET PASSWORD FOR 'druser'@$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST= PASSWORD("password");
#GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON drupal2.* TO druser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON drupal2.* TO $user@$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST IDENTIFIED BY $pass;
#GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON drupal.* TO $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME@$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST  IDENTIFIED BY $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
cd ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/repo/php
    chmod  755 . -R
    rm -rf *
if [[ 1=2 ]];then
    drush dl openpublic #--drupal-project-rename=folder_name
    mv open*/* ./
    cd pro*/openpu*
    drush make --prepare-install build-openpublic.make openpublic
rm -rf ~/app-root/data/sites/default/settings.php
fi
echo " \$options['backup-dir'] = '/tmp';">> ~/.drush/drushrc.php
cd ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/repo/php
nohup sh -c "export PATH=${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/drush:$PATH && drush dl openpublic"> $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/drush_site_install_1_1.log /dev/null 2>&1 &  
tail -f  $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/drush_site_install_1_1.log
cd ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/repo/php && mv */* './' && cd pro*/openpu* 
nohup sh -c "export PATH=${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/drush:$PATH  && drush make --prepare-install build-openpublic.make openpublic &&\
 cd ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/repo/php &&\
 drush site-install openpublic --db-url=mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD@$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/drupal2 --site-name=${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}  --account-name='ss' --account-pass='ss' --yes"> $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/drush_site_install_1_2.log /dev/null 2>&1 &  
tail -f  $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/drush_site_install_1_2.log
#drush site-install weebpal --db-url=mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD@$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/$OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME  --site-name=${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}  --account-name='ss' --account-pass='ss'  --account-mail='ss3@elec-lab.tk' --site-mail='ss3@elec-lab.tk' --yes 
#nohup sh -c "drush site-install themebrain_profile --db-url=mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD@$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/drupal2 --site-name=${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}  --account-name='ss' --account-pass='ss'  --account-mail='ss3@elec-lab.tk' --site-mail='ss3@elec-lab.tk' --yes ">$OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/drush_site_install_1_2.log /dev/null 2>&1 &  tail -f  $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/drush_site_install_1_2.log  
#drush site-install opendeals --db-url=mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD@$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/$OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME --site-name=${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}  --account-name='ss' --account-pass='ss'  --account-mail=ss3@elec-lab.tk --yes

#drush site-install openpublic --db-url=mysql://druser:password@$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/drupal2 --site-name=${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}  --account-name='ss' --account-pass='ss' --yes

#drush site-install openpublic --site-name=${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME} --account-pass=$admin_pwd --db-url=mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD@$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/$OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME --yes
#mysql -u $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME  -h $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST drupal <

########DONE ##################

echo " \$options['backup-dir'] = '/tmp';">> ~/.drush/drushrc.php
### drush backup database###
drush sql-dump > /tmp/database-backup.sql
### drush restore database###
mysqldump -u $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT  $OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME < database-backup.sql
mysqldump -u USERNAME -p'PASSWORD' DATABASENAME > /path/to/backup_dir/database-backup.sql
drush sql-cli < ~/my-sql-dump-file-name.sql
drush bam-backup


####################################
nohup sh -c " wget  -P ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/repo/php --mirror --user=u220290147 --password=ss123456 ftp://93.188.160.83:21/"> $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/python_modules_install_1_1.log /dev/null 2>&1 &  
tail -f  $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/python_modules_install_1_1.log
cd ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/repo/php/*
nohup sh -c "zip -r elec-lab.zip . "> $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/zip.log /dev/null 2>&1 &  
tail -f  $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/zip.log

/tmp/tmp/tb/sites/all/modules

~/app-root/data/sites/all/modules
mkdir ~/app-root/data/sites/all/libraries
mv -n /tmp/tmp/tb/sites/all/libraries/*  ~/app-root/data/sites/all/libraries
mkdir ~/app-root/data/sites/all/themes
mv -n /tmp/tmp/tb/sites/all/themes/*  ~/app-root/data/sites/all/themes
mv -n /tmp/tmp/tb/sites/all/*  ~/app-root/data/sites/all/
mv -n /tmp/tmp/tb/sites/*  ~/app-root/data/sites/
mv -n /tmp/tmp/tb/sites/all/modules/*  ~/app-root/data/sites/all/modules
mkdir ~/app-root/data/downloads/drupal-7.34/profiles/themebrain_profile
mv -n /tmp/tmp/tb/profiles/themebrain_profile/*  ~/app-root/data/downloads/drupal-7.34/profiles/themebrain_profile

mv ~/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/install_profiles/standard ~/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/install_profiles/standard1
mkdir ~/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/install_profiles/standard
mv -n /tmp/op/openpublic-7.x-1.x-dev/profiles/openpublic/* ~/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/install_profiles/standard
chmod 755 ~/app-root/data/sites/default/settings.php
rm -rf ~/app-root/data/sites/default/settings.php

chmod 755 ~/app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/action_hooks/deploy
nohup sh -c "./app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/action_hooks/deploy "> $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/deploy.log /dev/null 2>&1 &  tail -f  $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/deploy.log  
#tail -f  $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/deploy.log

#nohup sh -c "wget http://dl1.sarzamindownload.com/sdlftpuser/92/07/10/Android.Bootcamp_Part2.rar "> $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/zip2.log /dev/null 2>&1 &  
#tail -f  $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/zip2.log
rm drush_download.py
cat <<'EOF'  >> drush_download.py

import subprocess
import ast
st1='"Nodeblock, Follow, Securepages, Addthis, Twitter_pull, Comment_notify, Context_field, Entity_autocomplete, Views_boxes, Delta, Delta_ui, Context_condition_admin_theme, Context_breadcrumb_current_page, Context_bool_field, Nodeconnect, Openpublic_splash, Phase2_profile, Openpublic_breaking_news, Openpublic_comments, Openpublic_base_fields, Openpublic_defaults, Openpublic_home_page_feature, Openpublic_most_popular, Openpublic_person, Openpublic_person_leadership, Openpublic_site_page, Openpublic_webform, Openpublic_editors_choice, Openpublic_captcha, Openpublic_media_room, Openpublic_menu, Openpublic_menu_utility, Openpublic_menu_footer, Openpublic_pages, Openpublic_accessibility, Openpublic_filters, Openpublic_comments_default, Openpublic_webform_defaults"'
st1='"Addthis, Openpublic_splash, Phase2_profile, Openpublic_breaking_news, Openpublic_comments, Openpublic_base_fields, Openpublic_defaults, Openpublic_home_page_feature, Openpublic_most_popular, Openpublic_person, Openpublic_person_leadership, Openpublic_site_page, Openpublic_webform, Openpublic_editors_choice, Openpublic_captcha, Openpublic_media_room, Openpublic_menu, Openpublic_menu_utility, Openpublic_menu_footer, Openpublic_pages, Openpublic_accessibility, Openpublic_filters, Openpublic_comments_default, Openpublic_webform_defaults"'
st1=st1.lower()
st1=st1.replace(',',"','").replace('"',"'")
st2='"['+st1+']"';st2=st2.replace('"','')

ss=ast.literal_eval(st2)
#print ss

print st
for module in ss:
    try:
        st='drush dl '+module+' -Y ';print st
        awk_sort = subprocess.Popen( [st ], stdin= subprocess.PIPE, stdout= subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
        awk_sort.wait()
        output = awk_sort.communicate()[0]
        print output.rstrip()
    except:
        print 'module '+module+' could not bin installed !!!'
#print "END"
EOF
#python drush_download.py
 drush site-install standard --site-name=${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME} --account-pass=$admin_pwd --db-url=mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD@$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/$OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME --yes
nohup sh -c "python drush_download.py"> $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/drush_download.log /dev/null 2>&1 &  
tail -f  $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/drush_download.log

#nohup sh -c "zip  -rT9 ferdowsi-elec-labs_tk.zip '${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/tmp/.'"> $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/python_ftp_sync_download.log /dev/null 2>&1 &  
#nohup sh -c "cd ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}/app-root/runtime/srv/tmp/ && zip  -rT9 ferdowsi-elec-labs_tk.zip ."> $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/python_ftp_sync_download.log /dev/null 2>&1 &  
#tail -f  $OPENSHIFT_LOG_DIR/python_ftp_sync_download.log
```